# Need a smart contract to get rewards from ethereum mining?

Tags: go-ethereum

Do I need a smart contract to get rewards credited to my account while mining ethereum?

Answer (score 0):

No, In the mining pool you would put your ETH address.
They will send you the funds to that address which you have set.

Comment: Thanks you @Bryant. What in case of solo mining?